# drawImage not drawing at all, can't find the mistake

Tags: java

I'm new at Java and I'm trying to make a chess with it for training.
I'm having some trouble with the Graphic methods though.
I listed the functions which the mistake could have been in.
The code below shows a function called in main.
This function is inside my package that handle Graphic stuff.

```
public class GUI_main extends JComponent{

    private final int tam = 100;
    private final int tamTab = 8 * tam;
    Image torre;

    public void inicializaTabuleiro(Torre t)
    { //Sets the window properties and the "tile" proper image.
        JFrame janela = new JFrame("Xadrez");
        janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        janela.setSize(816, 839);
        janela.getContentPane().add(new GUI_main());
        janela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        janela.setResizable(false);
        janela.setVisible(true);
        paintPeca(t); /*this one is the function that sets the correct image
        for the tile that will be on the board*/
        System.out.println("Janela inicializada com sucesso!");
    }
    ...
```

next one is the "paintPeca" function, which should initialize "Image torre".

```
public void paintPeca(Torre t) 
{
    System.out.println(t.imgPeca());
    torre = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(t.imgPeca());
}
```

and finally my paint function:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    
    while(y<tamTab) //draw board
    {
        if(y%200 == 0) 
        {
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, tam, tam));
        x = x + tam;
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, tam, tam));
        x = x + tam;
        }
        else
        {
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, tam, tam));
            x = x + tam;
            g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, tam, tam));
            x = x + tam;
        }
        if(x == tamTab)
        {
            y = y + tam;
            x = 0;
        }
    }

    x = 14;
    y = 19;

    g2.drawImage(torre, x, y, this); //draw tower
    g2.finalize();
    ...
```

Together these functions should have draw a board and a tower on it.
It's showing me the board, but not the tower (Image torre), and I do not have a clue on the reason.
"t.imgPeca()" returns a string (path to image), and it's correct, as I have tested before.
Since I'm new at Java this might be some kind of of silly mistake, but I have not found the answer in other pages of stack that talked about the drawImage function.

Comment: ok, just solved it doing "private static Image torre;", but can someone tell me why? I put this question here because I spent hours and hours looking on APIs for the mistake, it was pure luck that I made it work now.

Comment: The static keyword makes it so that your `torre` is shared among all instances of your class. So all your changes to `torre` are reflected in the rest of the class